# Custom wordpress widget occurs error

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, widget, syntax-error

I have an error after I pass my whole site to another server. I made it using Duplicator Plugin.

The error is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/gestor/public_html/wp-content/themes/gestor/includes/widgets/widget-button.php on line 90
```

The line number 90 in widget-button.php is:

```
// register Button_Widget widget
add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
  register_widget( 'Button_Widget' );
});
```

In Functions.php I load the widget using:

```
/**
 * Load widgets.
 */
require THEME_DIR_PATH . '/includes/widgets.php';
require THEME_DIR_PATH . '/includes/widgets/widget-button.php';
```

I had the same files in my last server and I haven't got any errors. Could someone take a look at this ?

Comment: according to me share your two included file code here. they are doing something wrong with out looking at your  that code we cannot say anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your PHP version. According to the docs at http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php anonymous functions became available in 5.3.0.

Amend your code to:

```
add_action('widgets_init','register_my_widget');
function register_my_widget()
{
    register_widget( 'Button_Widget' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, mine is **PHP Version 5.2.17** . Is this possible to change the code of the function that register my widget without update the php version ?

Comment: I have made it like that: `add_action( 'widgets_init', register_widget( 'Button_Widget' ));` but now I have the warning: 
`Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/gestor/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 888 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/gestor/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 906 Warning: call_user_func_array(): First argument is expected to be a valid callback, '' was given in /home/gestor/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298`

Comment: Have amended my answer to provide the code you need.